# Google feed load API, Start index

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rss, google-api

I am using Google feed load API service, to parse a Rss feed. The idea is that I want to load the feeds separately and not to load a big amount of feeds in one call.

It is going to be like 20 items on page load,  for example and if I click  "more button" is going to be +20 feeds.

The feed url is:

```
var api = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&callback=?&q=" + encodeURIComponent(url);
api += "&num=20";
api += "&output=json_xml"
```

the issue is, I cannot find "start-index" or "page" parameter in JSON callback, to get next 20 items without to load first 20 one more time .

There is a way or a solution what can have this logic 
***Using JS/jQuery*** ?

Thanks everyone !